# Como ordenar vetor em ordem decrescente?

Tags: java, array

Como coloco um vetor em ordem decrescente?

```
    public static void vetor() {
      int[] vet = {
          7,
          4,
          10,
          8,
          2,
          5
      };
      Arrays.sort(vet);
      //Comando para colocar em ordem decrescente.
      for (int i = 0; i < vet.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(vet[i] + "");
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para ordenar um array em ordem decrescente, você pode utilizar o algoritmo de ordenação [bubble sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort):

```
for (int i = 1; i < vet.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (vet[i] > vet[j]) {
            int temp = vet[i];
            vet[i] = vet[j];
            vet[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

São dois laços que vão comparando os valores de dois em dois do array, quando um valor na posição posterior for maior que o na posição anterior(`if (vet[i] > vet[j]`), ele troca ambos de posição. E assim segue comparando até os dois últimos elementos.

Veja funcionando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/c6Zsz8)

---

Outra solução interessante que encontrei no SOEn é essa:

```
for(int i=0;i<vet.length;i++) {

    vet[i]=-vet[i];
}

Arrays.sort(vet);

for(int i=0;i<vet.length;i++) {

    vet[i]=-vet[i]; 
}
```

O código acima faz:

- multiplica todos os indices do vetor por -1;
- ordena o vetor de forma ascendente;
- multiplica novamente todos os indices por -1

O resultado é o mesmo, como pode ser visto no [ideone](https://ideone.com/Ti54Kt).

Comment: Eu prefiro a segunda solução: ela é feita sobre um algoritmo de ordenação `n log(n)`

Comment: Vi essa [nova funcionalidade](https://github.com/mintern-java/primitive#where-are-all-the-source-files) do Java 8 @diegofm, o que acha?

Comment: @Marconi pra ser sincero, nunca utilizei essa lib ai. O apache commons também tem um recurso pra ordenar array de primitivos, mas como eu tambem nunca utilizei, só coloquei formas utilizando métodos nativos. Se fosse até um array de Integer, da pra utilizar comparator e ficaria mais facil fazer isso.

Comment: @diegofm eu fiquei curioso demais nessa lib, como estou enferrujado no Java e não tenho a IDE só dei um lida mesmo. Acho que ficaria interessante na sua resposta!

Comment: @Marconi vou tentar testar depois, em java8 tem alguns recursos que eu ainda to meio desatualizado kkk

Comment: @diegofm tranquilo, já deixei meu +1!

Comment: Nós fizemos uma pesquisa na faculdade, usando o Bubble Sorte, Quick Sort, e outros, nos Sistemas Operacionais Windows 10 e Linux, com processadores iguais e diferentes, pois foram vários acadêmicos, o `Bubble Sort` foi o mais lento, e ponha lento nisso.

Answer (score 0):

Que  tal fazer assim?

```
Arrays.sort(vet);
int[] vetAux;

int contador = 0;
for(int i=vet.length - 1;i >= 0;i--) {
    vetAux[contador]=vet[i]; 
    contador++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, segue o meu código. Acredito que na parte final, deva ajudar.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverso {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Quantos números inteiros? ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] num = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Digite " + n + " números.");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            num[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        Arrays.sort(num); //Comando para ordenar os números do vetor em ordem crescente
        System.out.println("Em ordem decrescente.");
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(num[n - i - 1]); //Necessário subtrair o índice por -1
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

//Imprimindo Array em ordem decrescente

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int valor[] = new int[1000];
    for(int i =0;i<valor.length;i++){
        valor[i] = valor.length - i;
        System.out.println(valor[i]);

    }


}
```

}

Answer (score -3):

```
//Ordem Decrescente

import java.util.Scanner;
public class OrdemDecrescente {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     int cont = 1;
     int[] vet = new int[5];

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < vet.length; i++){  
        System.out.print("Digite "+cont+"° número: \t");
        vet[i] = sc.nextInt();
        cont++;
        }

    for (int i = 1; i < vet.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (vet[i] > vet[j]) {
                int aux = vet[i];
                vet[i] = vet[j];
                vet[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Array em ordem decrescente:");
    for (int n : vet) {
        System.out.print(n + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O que sua resposta tem de diferentes das respostas já postadas? Não vi nada de diferente

Comment: Um exemplo de junção de pedaços de códigos... nada mais